# How to code softmax function using Python on tensorflow graph

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to program the softmax function from scratch using Python on tensorflow mood.

```
def sigmoid(p):
    return tf.cond(p >= 0, lambda: 1 / (1 + tf.exp(-p)), \
                           lambda: tf.exp(p) / (1 + tf.exp(p)))
```

While running this code chunk, I got this traceback:

`InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?,256], [?,256].`

Here's my reproducible code:

```py
# 1st hidden layer
W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=(784, 256), dtype=tf.float32, initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", shape=(256), dtype=tf.float32, initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)

# 2nd hidden layer
W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", shape=(256, 10), dtype=tf.float32, initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", shape=(10), dtype=tf.float32, initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)

def sigmoid(z):
    """Numerically stable sigmoid function."""
    return tf.where(z >= 0, 1 / (1 + tf.exp(-z)), tf.exp(z) / (1 + tf.exp(z))) 

### Compute predictions
logits = X @ W1 + b1 
probas = sigmoid(logits) 
y_pred = probas @ W2 + b2

def softmax(z):  ## this approach provides numerical stability
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in z."""
    e = tf.exp(z - tf.reduce_max(z))
    return e / tf.reduce_sum(e)

### Cross-Entropy loss 
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(softmax(y_pred)), reduction_indices=[1]))

lr = 0.01
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
step = optimizer.minimize(cost)  #
```

This gives me a very bad score with `BATCH_SIZE = 512` and `EPOCHS= 55`

```
Test cost after 10 epochs: 6.3319
Test cost after 30 epochs: 6.2753
Test cost after 50 epochs: nan

OPTIMIZATION IS DONE!
Score = 0.098982
```

Comment: Change to `return tf.where(p >= 0, 1 / (1 + tf.exp(-p)),tf.exp(p) / (1 + tf.exp(p)))`.

Comment: Thanks, @giser_yugang. This gives me `nan` while I am training my model.  `logits = X @ W1 + b1 
probas = sigmoid(logits)
y_pred = probas @ W2 + b2` where `sigmoid(p) : return tf.where(p >= 0, 1 / (1 + tf.exp(-p)),tf.exp(p) / (1 + tf.exp(p)))`

Comment: Do you have `nan` values when you use other activation functions?

Comment: When I tried with `tf.nn.sigmoid() ` it works well without  any `nan`

Comment: So strange. Can you give a complete reproducible code?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @giser_yugang. I have updated my post with complete reproducible code.

Comment: Please, see complete code source [here](https://github.com/ftakelait/2D-CNN-for-MNIST-digit-recognition-from-scratch.git).

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43544007/10543310) but I didn't find its relationship with my code.

Comment: Some gradients become `nan` during training. Maybe you need `tf.clip_by_value` to  clip gradients like `capped_grads_vars = [[tf.clip_by_value(g, -5, 5), v] for g, v in grad_list]
update = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=capped_grads_vars)`

Comment: How can use this for my `sigmoid` function, please?

Comment: You just add it to replace `update = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=grad_list)` in your github code.

Comment: @giser_yugang, you mean instead of using `optimizer.minimize(cost)` I need to `update`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193559/discussion-between-joe-and-giser-yugang).